# MySQL inserting with Polish signs

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, insert, collation

I've got MySQL db which has set character_set to utf-8, and collation=utf8_polish_ci.
When I'm inserting records with polish signs through MySQL Workbench, everything seems to be ok.
But when I'm inserting records through my asp.net site, polish signs are converted to normal signs like a,e,o. WHy is that happening?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection character set (when connecting from asp.net to MySQL). See e.g. http://forums.asp.net/t/1619144.aspx/1 for an example of setting the connection charset.

Comment: My character_set_connection is set to utf8

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the culture setting as in this link?

[ASP.NET Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not culture setting. I checked MySQL Command before firing and it had polish signs in query.

Comment: Are you running this locally, or does it run through an application/hosting server?